# C struct with uint8_t variable in nodejs

Tags: c, node.js

I have problem to create struct in node.js, written in C language like this:

```
struct {
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t *y;
    uint8_t z[16];
};
```

I try to use ref, ref-struct, ffi libs, but without success.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you `#include <stdint.h>` before using unit8_t?

Comment: In C code snippet yes, but my question how to use library like stdint.h in node.js.

Answer (score -1):

```
const ArrayType = require('ref-array');
const StructType = require('ref-struct');

exports.StructName = StructType({
    x: 'uint8'
    y: ref.refType('uint8'),
    z: ArrayType('uint8', 16)
})
```

Comment: Your answer is only code. Please explain how it answers the question

Answer (score -2):

You are defining structure wrongly it must be defined as:

```
struct ref{
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t *y;
    uint8_t z[16];
};
```

or

```
struct _ref_{
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t *y;
    uint8_t z[16];
};
typedef struct _ref_ REF
```

or

```
typedef struct _ref_{
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t *y;
    uint8_t z[16];
}REF;
```

Comment: My fault for incomplete definition, I just want to mention that I have structure like this and rewrite it on node.js